# 2D object movement in square path in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

im new to unity game development. i have to develop simple 2D object movement in square path during mouse button clicked. just simple square/circle 2D spirite move in square path during mouse clicked

```
  using System.Collections;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
  using UnityEngine;

  public class mousetomove : MonoBehaviour
  {
  public float speed = 5.0f;
  private Transform target1;
  private Transform target2;
  private Transform hero ;
    
  // Start is called before the first frame update
  void Start()
  {
    hero = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Hero").GetComponent<Transform>();
    target1 = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Transform>();
  }

  // Update is called once per frame
   void Update()
  {

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
       

        if (hero == target1)
        {
       transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target2.position ,
      *Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }

 }    
 }
```

Comment: `i have to develop ...` good luck with that! Once you have done your own research, tried to implement it and then have a **specific** issue during a **specific** implementation we are happy to help you here :) Otherwise please ask an actual question, what is your issue / not behaving as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Here you are trying to check if hero is equal to target, this will not happen I think, you have to compare positions but even doing so positions will probably not be the same but just very close. You are using MoveTowards, thats good but you have to be changing the target, like maybe have 4 targets in an array I guess